# I tried sending 300 mails at a once to same email id from my program. I am getting the below SMTP Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

> Error: System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: Failure sending mail. ---> System.ArgumentException: The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding asynchronous method on this class.  Parameter name: asyncResult     at System.Net.Mime.MimeBasePart.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at System.Net.Mail.Message.EndSend(IAsyncResult asyncResult)     at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.SendMessageCallback(IAsyncResult result)     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

```
private void DispatchMail(MailMessage message, MessageTrackerObject trackInfo)
{
    SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient();
    mailClient.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[(Constants.FAXSETTINGS_SMTPSERVER)];
    mailClient.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[(Constants.FAXSETTINGS_SMTPPORT)]);
    //mailClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;


    NetworkCredential ntCredential = new NetworkCredential();

    if (GetStaticSetting(Constants.APPCONFIG_KEY_MAILWINDOWSAUTH).ToLower() == "true")
    {
        //mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ntCredential.UserName = GetStaticSetting(Constants.APPCONFIG_KEY_MAILUSERID);
        ntCredential.Password = GetStaticSetting(Constants.APPCONFIG_KEY_MAILPASSWORD);
        mailClient.Credentials = ntCredential;
        mailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    }

    mailClient.EnableSsl = GetStaticSetting(Constants.APPCONFIG_KEY_MAIL_SSL).ToLower() == "true";
    mailClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(MailClient_SendCompleted);
    mailClient.SendAsync(message, trackInfo);
    //mailClient.Send(message);
}

private void MailClient_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    string error = "";
    MessageTrackerObject data = (MessageTrackerObject)e.UserState;

    string msg = string.Format("File: {0}", data.Info);
    try
    {
        foreach (string serial in data.Serials)
        {
            if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                error = e.Error != null ? String.Format(" #Error: {0}", e.Error.ToString()) : "";
                string cancelled = string.Format("{0} Send canceled. {1}", msg, error);
                SetFaxStatus(serial, FaxStatus.Cancelled, cancelled);
            }
            else if (e.Error != null)
            {
                error = String.Format("{0} #Error: {1}", msg, e.Error.ToString());
                SetFaxStatus(serial, FaxStatus.Error, error);
            }
            else
            {
                SetFaxStatus(serial, FaxStatus.Sent, string.Format("{0} Mail sent successfully.", msg));
            }
        }
        //release resource
        data.Message.Dispose();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
}
```

How can i avoid this error?

Comment: How about displaying some code? There is absolutely nothing to go off of here. Google the error message if that is all you have.

Comment: Can you post the mail client object code, specially the SendAsync?

Comment: @user3332414 I've added an answer

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the problem here is that the same instance of `MailMessage` is passed to `DispatchMail`. `MailMessage` is not thread-safe by design, and each `SmtpClient.SendAsync` is internally invoking `Message.BeginSend`.

So, when several threads are attempting to send same `MailMessage`, there is a race condition when calling `Message.EndSend`. If `EndSend` is invoked by the same thread which called `BeginSend` - we are in luck. If not - exception from above is raised,

> The IAsyncResult object was not returned from the corresponding
>   asynchronous method on this class

Solution here is either to copy `MailMessage` for each call of `SendAsync`, or use `SendAsync` overload which accepts 5 parameters:

```
void SendAsync(string from, string recipients, string subject, string body, object token)
```

Edit:
This exception is very easy to reproduce, to prove that MailMessage is not thread-safe. You may get several exceptions, `IAsyncResult` one from above, or `Item has already been added` when populating headers:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
class App
{
  static void Main()
  {
     var mail = new MailMessage("aaa@bbb.ccc", "ddd@eee.fff", "Test Subj", "Test Body");
     var client1 = new SmtpClient("localhost");
     var client2 = new SmtpClient("localhost");
     var task1 = client1.SendMailAsync(mail);
     var task2 = client2.SendMailAsync(mail);
     Task.WhenAll(task1, task2).Wait();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ManualResetEvent` object. I'm guessing the SmtpClient is being disposed that's why it's losing the subscription to `MailClient_SendCompleted`

```
ManualResetEvent resetEvent;
private void DispatchMail(MailMessage message, MessageTrackerObject trackInfo)
{
    // other code here
    resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    mailClient.EnableSsl = GetStaticSetting(Constants.APPCONFIG_KEY_MAIL_SSL).ToLower() == "true";
    mailClient.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(MailClient_SendCompleted);
    mailClient.SendAsync(message, trackInfo);
    resetEvent.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)); // waits for 5 seconds
    //mailClient.Send(message);
}

private void MailClient_SendCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    resetEvent.Set(); // removes the wait after successfully sending
    string error = "";
    MessageTrackerObject data = (MessageTrackerObject)e.UserState;
    // other code here
}
```